# merge and filter unique times from 6 columns in a mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a database table with 6 time zone fields called time1, time2, time3, time4, time5 and time6. I need to query these fields and pick out one of each times and order them ascendingly. Some of these times may be blank so if one entry has 
0900, 1200, 1500 and another has 0900, 1100, 1200, 1500, 1530, 1800 and 2200. this would result in 0900, 1100, 1200, 1500, 1530, 1800 and 2200 being output.

here is some sample code:

```
$rndQuery=$this->DB->prepare("select time1, time2, time3, time4, time5, time6 
                                from customer
                                where customer_cycle_uid=".$this->DB->quote_smart($cycleRow['uid'])."
                                    and customer_uid=".$this->DB->quote_smart($customerRow['uid'])."
                                    and (blistered='1')
                                    and (prn!='1')");
```

as you can see I only select the times 1-6 because there are other fields I don't need at this moment.

Comment: Are you trying to order columns?
Your output will come in order that you selected in 1st line. If you say SELECT time4, time3, time2, time1 .... it will come out in that order.

Comment: I am trying to select all entries to do with that customer. then select all the times. then filter the unique times giving me a list of times to do with that customer (one of each)